# How can I populate an online web form and get results from a standalone application?

Tags: javascript, html, url, webforms

I am trying to write code for a standalone application that will access a website URL and I want the program to pass data to the website's form, calculate, and then return its result. All of that without requiring the website to be opened and manually filled out.

I am aware this is possible by passing parameters through the URL on some websites with a form but that doesn't work on the website we are trying to do this with.

Does anyone know a way to use JavaScript to do so? Everything I find when I research this topic gives info on how to do it to a website you are creating and I can't do that to this website since it is already made. I am confused how I would get my JavaScript code to run on this website if I did write any.

Comment: Well that web form still very likely sends a POST request to somewhere (then there is no problem) :P It would be nice if you provided an example so we could see what your problem even is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an http "POST" request (because you already said a "GET" request doesn't work.

What object you use to make that http request depends on your environment (where will you run your Javascript code). ex: XMLHTTPRequest if your JavaSscript runs in a browser, WinHTTP if it runs in windows script host or MS Excel..etc..etc..

You may have to provide a specific header in your http request. Maybe a Cookie header. Maybe a Referrer header. You can figure this out by looking at what a normal browser sends (ie: use Developer Tools (F12) in your browser)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use POST, rather than GET, which is, what I am assuming you have now.

```
method="POST"
```

rather than...

```
method="GET"
```

I am not super experienced in JavaScript, but I do know it has a bit of a reputation for being weird in apps when there are webpages involved.